# Place block on block creation drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8

We want to place block to region on block creation time. How can we do that?
   I mean programatically how can we add regions while creating the block.

Comment: Did you ever find anything?

Answer (score 0):

Add regions? Can you use the regions that are already defined for your theme?

Comment: Its not adding new regions. By default we need plaace the block to regions for a custom block. We want to place the blocks directly  to hidden regions after block creation. How can we do it in a custom module ?